# slow scrolling when using BaseAdapter and ImageView Helper for downloading images

Tags: android, imageview, baseadapter

In my app, I am using [UrlImageViewHelper](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper) library. At run-time the app will get an xml file from server and related images which exceed 300. I am facing a problem related to the speed of scrolling. When I scroll down faster, it gets stuck, works very slow. I tried without downloading images and it worked just fine. Then I made some changes to the Library's image scaling code, but it didn't help. Even I tried the method *loadUrlDrawable()* termed "snazzy fast loading" from that library, unfortunately, still no success.

Here is how my app might look like:

[image]

Xml file for adapter is simple, here is JAVA code:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public MyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
    TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
    TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
    song = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_TITLE));
    artist.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_ARTIST));
    duration.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DURATION));

   UrlImageViewCallback imgCallback = new UrlImageViewCallback() {
   @Override
   public void onLoaded(ImageView imageView, Drawable loadedDrawable,
    String url, boolean loadedFromCache) {
     thumb_image.setImageDrawable(loadedDrawable);
   }
  };
   UrlImageViewHelper.loadUrlDrawable(thumb_image.getContext(), Const.URL_SMALL_IMAGES + restoran.getId() + "/1_m.jpg", imgCallback);
 }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Any help will really be appreciated.

Comment: Use Lazy loader to display image in the ImageView also use the View-Holder pattern while implementing adapter for ListView

Comment: why didn't you use ViewHolder in your class?? which helps you to hold imageview with data also.

Comment: In fact, I have already used ViewHolder, but didn't help

Comment: Thanks guys, LazyLoader did the trick!